# what wrong with map is not a function?

Tags: reactjs

Please help me with this

I just learn about ReactJs and now I learn about get data from Api, before that i use fetch to get api and it normal but when i use Axios and have that problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios'
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    Axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://reqres.in/api/users"
    }).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: res.data
      })
      console.log(res.data)

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)

    })
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items = [] } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {items.map(function (item, i) {
            return <div key={i}>
              <p>{item.id}</p>
              <img src={item.avatar} alt="Card" />
            </div>
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is data from reqres

```
    {"page":1,"per_page":3,"total":12,"total_pages":4,"data":
    [  {"id":1,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"},
 {"id":2,"first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"},
  {"id":3,"first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"}
]}
```

Here is error from react

[Error from react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK9ef.png)

I just want to show my data :(

Comment: You are setting items to res.data. Have you tried to print out items?

Comment: I use fetch to get data and is work but I use Axios and is have that error ? I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

looks like res.data is not something you can loop over it. try to check what's inside it

edit:

as you can see from you output:

```
{"page":1,"per_page":3,"total":12,"total_pages":4,"data":
    [  {"id":1,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"},
 {"id":2,"first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"},
  {"id":3,"first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"}
]}
```

your informations are inside the data property, so, just loop over it:

```
 {items.data.map(function (item, i) {
            return <div key={i}>
              <p>{item.id}</p>
              <img src={item.avatar} alt="Card" />
            </div>
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API response the statement should be

```
items: res.data.data
```

Comment: but why i use fetch to get data: "items: res.data" is work?? Can i ask why ?

Comment: when you use fetch and say response.json() you are actually fetching the data inside your response.

Comment: Oh now i get it, tks a lot :)